# Delete doesn't trigger a restart event in nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Is deleting a file not supposed to trigger a restart event? How can I capture a file being deleted? I've tried the following:

```
$ node
> require('nodemon')({
    ext: '*.*',
    exec: 'true',
    ignore: false,
    watch: process.cwd()
  }).
  on('restart', console.log);
```

Now, when I `touch abc` (in another terminal) I see a `console.log` message:

```
> [ '/abc' ]
```

However nothing happens when I `rm abc`.

I've also opened an issue [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/400).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the loop on this, for now this is not possible. See linked issue in the question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative npm package, `watch`, reacts to deletions